# mysql query left join three tables showing all data

Tags: mysql

I have an issue in using left join for my 3 tables. i have employee table, attendance table and leave table

I have a table of employee

employee

```
employee_id   | employee_name
     1        |  George
```

attendance

```
 employee_id    |  date
       1        | 2014-01-02
       1        | 2014-01-03
```

leave_schedule

```
employee_id    |     leave_datedate  |    reason
       1       |       2014-01-01    |  sick leave
       1       |       2014-01-02    |  vacation leave
```

here is my query

`select e.employee_id, e.employee_name, a.date, l.leave_date, l.reason from employee e
left join attendance a ON a.employee_id = e.employee_id
left join leave_schedule l on l.employee_id = e.employee_id and a.date = l.leave_date
where e.employee_id = 1`

there result is

```
employee_id   |   employee_name  |  date         |   leave_date   | reason
    1         |      george      |  2014-01-02   |    2014-01-02  | vacation leave
    1         |      george      |  2014-01-03   |    null        |  null
```

i want to include the sick leave . how to do that? is it full outer join?

expected result

```
    employee_id   |   employee_name  |  date         |   leave_date   | reason
        1         |      george      |  2014-01-01   |    2014-01-01  | sick leave
        1         |      george      |  2014-01-02   |    2014-01-02  | vacation leave
        1         |      george      |  2014-01-03   |    null        |  null
```

here is my sqlfiddle

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/ad86b/1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do this with a more complicated query.  Here is an approach that uses aggregation and `union all` to bring the leave dates together:

```
select e.employee_id, e.employee_name, al.date, al.leave_date, al.reason
from employee e left join
     (select employee_id, date, leave_date, max(reason) as reason
      from (select a.employee_id, a.date, a.date as leave_date, NULL as reason
            from attendance a
            union all
            select l.employee_id, l.leave_date, l.leave_date, l.reason
            from leave_schedule l
           ) al
      group by employee_id, date, leave_date
     ) al
     ON al.employee_id = e.employee_id
where e.employee_id = 1;
```

Comment: this is good. i want to understand this more. why did you use max(reason) ?